# Past perfect tense vs present perfect tense usage

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, past-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

David got a message telling him that he has/had won the prize.

Here which is to be used ? Has or had ?

Comment: related: 1. [I asked if he speaks/spoke English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244812/i-asked-if-he-speaks-spoke-english), 2. [Felt + present/ past (back shifting )](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270269/felt-present-past-back-shifting) 3. [Reported speech: why is the past perfect the right answer here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254467/reported-speech-why-is-the-past-perfect-the-right-answer-here)

Answer (score 2):

"Had" in this instance.  He'd already won it and being notified after that fact had occurred made it past-tense.

Comment: I agree that 'had' to be used but why do I often see people like newspaper editor, noted authors using 'has' is such cases. They simoly don't back shift the tense.So can I say that 'has' is also grammatical ?

Comment: Have you followed modern journalism?  Their English is bordering on atrocious.  But, yes, I've seen that too.

Comment: So are they using it incorrectly or the use of 'has' is also acceptable ?

Comment: They are using "has" incorrectly.